# Prolog - Find a non-single list in a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

I have a 9x9 puzzle (list of lists). Each of his 9 lines has 9 lists with numbers. My goal is to find a non-single list on the puzzle.

```
choose([[H|T]|R], Pos):-  choose([[H|T]|R], 1, 1, Pos).
choose([[H|T]|R], 9, C, Pos):-
    length(H,X),
    X =:= 1,
    C1 is C+1,
    choose([T|R], 1, C1, Pos).

choose([[H|T]|R], L, C, Pos):-
    length(H,X),
    X =:= 1,
    L1 is L+1,
    choose([T|R],L1, C, Pos).
choose(_,L,C, (L,C)).
```

Although this code is not particulary good-looking, it should be working, but for some reason it does not...
Does anyone know a better way to solve this?

EDIT:

with this input:

```
 choose([[[1],[9],[7],[4],[3],[8],[5],[2],[6]],
 [[2],[6],[5],[7],[1],[9],[3],[8],[4]],
 [[4],[3,8],[3,8],[6],[2],[5],[1,9],[1,7],[7,9]],
 [[8],[2,5],[1,9],[2,5],[6],[1,7],[4],[3],[5,7,9]],
 [[5,7,9],[2,3,5],[1,3,9],[8],[4],[1,7],[2,9],[6],[5,7,9]],
 [[5,7],[4],[6],[2,5],[9],[3],[1,2],[1,7],[8]],
 [[5,9],[5,8],[8,9],[3],[7],[2],[6],[4],[1]],
 [[6],[1],[2],[9],[8],[4],[7],[5],[3]],
 [[3],[7],[4],[1],[5],[6],[8],[9],[2]]], Pos).

 The output should be Pos = (3,2) but it is Pos = (1,2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post some example queries that do work , and some example queries that do not work (also with expected results) ? also , you really really want to use clpfd for your math , especially for bactracking puzzles like sudoku , put ``:- (use_module(library(clpfd)))`` at the top of your file and then change ``X =:= 1`` to ``X #= 1`` and ``L1 is L+1`` to ``L1 #= L+1`` . note this is not a spurious or arcane suggestion , clpfd should always be used for math in prolog , =:= and is are severely limiting by comparison ... c.f. https://github.com/triska/clpfd/blob/master/README.md

Comment: i edited with an example

Comment: `choose(_,L,C, (L,C)).` needs some kind of condition on the first argument. Otherwise, it succeeds for any first argument, which seems wrong logically.

Answer (score 2):

Something simpler, based on [nth1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3)/3...

```
choose(Mat, (Row,Col)) :-
    nth1(Row, Mat, Cells),
    nth1(Col, Cells, C),
    nth1(Rc, Cells, C),
    Rc > Col.
```

yields

```
?- choose([[[1],[9],[7],[4],[3],[8],[5],[2],[6]],
|     [[2],[6],[5],[7],[1],[9],[3],[8],[4]],
|     [[4],[3,8],[3,8],[6],[2],[5],[1,9],[1,7],[7,9]],
|     [[8],[2,5],[1,9],[2,5],[6],[1,7],[4],[3],[5,7,9]],
|     [[5,7,9],[2,3,5],[1,3,9],[8],[4],[1,7],[2,9],[6],[5,7,9]],
|     [[5,7],[4],[6],[2,5],[9],[3],[1,2],[1,7],[8]],
|     [[5,9],[5,8],[8,9],[3],[7],[2],[6],[4],[1]],
|     [[6],[1],[2],[9],[8],[4],[7],[5],[3]],
|     [[3],[7],[4],[1],[5],[6],[8],[9],[2]]], Pos).
Pos =  (3, 2) ;
Pos =  (4, 2) ;
Pos =  (5, 1) ;
false.
```

**edit**

in Prolog, the number of arguments (arity) identifies the predicate, as well as the symbol (functor). An useful refinement of the snippet above could be

```
choose(Mat, (Row,Col)) :-
    choose(Mat, Row, Col,_).

choose(Mat, Row, C1,C2) :-
    nth1(Row, Mat, Cols),
    nth1(C1, Cols, Value),
    nth1(C2, Cols, Value),
    C2 > C1.
```

that is, choose/2 is implemented calling choose/4, that gives us the column of the second 'not-single'. Let's test on a 4x4 matrix

```
?- choose([
|    [1,2,3,4],
|    [5,6,5,8],
|    [9,0,1,9],
|    [3,3,5,6]], X).
X =  (2, 1) ;
X =  (3, 1) ;
X =  (4, 1) ;
false.
```

seems it's working...

Comment: nice solution !  It certainly seems a lot easier to use nth rather than trying to figure out a recursive solution .  Is there any reason why an nth solution is inferior ? performance ? non-logical ? (it seems to me that nth is (if anything) likely better for performance and easier the logical with) .

Comment: thanks! but shouldn´t the second answer be Pos = (3,3)? I tried on a 4x4 matrix and it didnt work properly

Comment: what is the difference between a funktor and a predicate ?

Comment: ['I don't mean my question above to be threatening .  I am not asking for a defiinition that is strictly correct according to the pre-existing literature for example .  I'm not being disingenous and I'm not going to jump all over you if you don't give the correct answer .']<--['I write all of that because that is a common social pattern .'] --> ['I ask because it seemed from your writing that yourself have a criteria of distinction for what is the  predicate is vs. what is the funktor .  It's an ongoing topic of investigation for me at the moment .']-->['Thanks !']-->[' P.S great edit @!'] .

Comment: @Kintalken: a functor it's the 'name' of a predicate. Must be an atom. Functor and arity together *define* a predicate identity.

Comment: But the objetive is to get the first, not the second 'non_single' list

Comment: @JoaoNunoPedro:  Prolog is *relational*, predicates are relations, can have multiple 'instances'. To limit to the first solution, wrap the call in once/1, or use a cut. But often it's better to reconsider *why* to limit to first solution....